# SVN Notifier won't update after changing password

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, change-password

I recently had to change my network password and now SVN Notifier will not update.

I suspect the new password is causing the issue, any idea how to update the password that SVN Notifier is using to access the repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My response is valid only if you are using a tool like TortoiseSVN which will store passwords for you.

You'll first have to remove the stored passwords you have in SVN by going to TortoiseSVN->Settings->Saved Data->Authentication Data->Clear  This will remove the old passwords for Tortoise.  After this you'll be required to re-authenticate your login when you try to update or commit.  If you save this authentication SVN Notifier can access that saved information and be able to connect to your repositories again.